# Three spinners in one Activity

Tags: java, android, layout

I have three spinners in one Activity , so I want to choose from one spinner then getting some specific values to the second spinner and after choose one of the second then getting some specific values to third spinner .

i have tired with using loops and switch case but i think it takes much time and long code .

is there is simple way to make this three spinner dependent to each other ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable spinner 2 in your layout, and then enable and populate it when spinner 1 item is selected. Then do the same for spinner 3 based on spinner 2.

```
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
      @Override
      public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
          // Enable Spinner 2
          // Set spinner 2 adapter
      }

      @Override
      public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
          // Disable spinner 2
          // Set spinner 2 adapter to empty list
      }
});
```

Comment: spinner one some value is selected by default how to remove this selection ?

Comment: You could add an item as the first selection that just has text like "Choose One..."